# How do I set up a full validator on the test network

Tags: stellar-core, validators

I am trying to learn about Stellar-core by configuring a full validator on the test network.

Using sample configs and input from [this post](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2522/how-to-configure-full-validator-node), my config looks like:

```
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/var/lib/stellar-core/buckets"
DATABASE="sqlite3:///var/lib/stellar-core/stellar.db"

ENTRY_CACHE_SIZE=4096
PREFETCH_BATCH_SIZE=1000
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
HTTP_MAX_CLIENT=128

COMMANDS=[
"ll?level=warning"
]

NODE_SEED="SA.................................."
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"
KNOWN_CURSORS=["HORIZON"]
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=1
CATCHUP_RECENT=100

[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="testnet.stellar.org"
QUALITY="HIGH"

[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.howitts.co.uk"
QUALITY="HIGH"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_testnet_1"
HOME_DOMAIN="testnet.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y"
ADDRESS="core-testnet1.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_testnet_2"
HOME_DOMAIN="testnet.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP"
ADDRESS="core-testnet2.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_testnet_3"
HOME_DOMAIN="testnet.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z"
ADDRESS="core-testnet3.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.local]
get="cp /var/lib/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /var/lib/stellar-core/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /var/lib/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}"
```

But this does not seem to be working and I get the following error when trying to create a db:

```
[root@proxmox107 ~]# runuser -l stellar -c '/usr/bin/stellar-core --conf /etc/stellar-core/stellar.cfg new-db'
runuser: warning: cannot change directory to /home/stellar: No such file or directory
2021-03-22T15:15:33.190 [default INFO] Config from /etc/stellar-core/stellar.cfg
2021-03-22T15:15:33.192 [default FATAL] Got an exception: Failed to parse '/etc/stellar-core/stellar.cfg' :Must specify a matching HOME_DOMAINS for self
2021-03-22T15:15:33.192 [default FATAL] Please report this bug along with this log file if this was not expected
```

I am really not sure where to go on this one. In the examples I've seen I don't see HOME_DOMAIN or HOME_DOMAINS set. What should the HOME_DOMAINS be matching with?

I also do not see where I should set my key's home domain. I have created a key at [Stellar Labs](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#account-creator?network=test) but I don't see where to add my home domain.

As I've only got this far, I have not set up a toml file (or even enabled the web server)

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is just misleading. The field that you're supposed to set is `NODE_HOME_DOMAIN` that must match your domain.

I opened https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/pull/2987 to fix this in both the error code and docs

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was experimenting this morning before I saw your answer. From my experimenting, it looks like both NODE_HOME_DOMAIN and HOME_DOMAIN must be set **and** the same or you can't do a new-db. If you set one without the other, or set them differently, it does not work, so it seems like a further bug and one of the parameters could be made redundant.

There also does not seem to be a check on the parameter as you can set it to anything (I tried `anything.here` and it worked as long as both were set). I can understand that.

I have commented on your bug report.